# Possible to specify the GUID when adding a List to a SPListCollection?

Tags: list, guid

I found [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms413986.aspx) which goes over how to add a list, but it doesn't seem possible to specify a GUID if you use this method.

Is there any way to create a list and specify the GUID?  I am trying to recreate several lists on a different server and if they do not have the same GUIDs other functionality may break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you can't.  You probably make it work by using the title of the list to get its instance instead of its internal GUID.

Comment: @Abe Miessler @Sébastien Levert, I think it is better to use url of the list's AllItems.aspx page, and use SPWeb.GetListFromUrl, because list Title can be easily changed by user through the GUI.

Comment: You are right.  In fact, I'm using a custom extension methods that allow me to get a list instance from its RootFolder name.  So it is by its URL that I'm getting it.  Working in a bilingual environment (French and English), I can't refer to a list name, because they usually have 2 of them.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to assign your own GUID when you create a list.