# Possible to find EVERYTHING that references a list using PowerShell or the Object Model?

Tags: 2010, list, guid

I recently did a migration from SharePoint 2007 to 2010.  In the end I had to re-implement a number of things (such as workflows) because they referenced lists, and the list GUIDs changed during the migration.  [I looked into creating a list with a specific GUID](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12987/possible-to-specify-the-guid-when-adding-a-list-to-a-splistcollection) but have come to the conclusion that it cannot be done.

My question is if it would be possible to find EVERYTHING that references a GUID for a list?  My hope is that I might be able to go the opposite way and update existing references to the old list GUID to point to the new list GUID.  It would have to be something I can automate, so I'm looking for things I can do with PowerShell or the Object Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think this is possible -it wont be easy thats for sure..

Lists are referenced in alot of places, it could be in views, list web parts, custom code, even declarative provisioning logic, workflows...

Even if you could, what would you do with the list? Not all guids would be possible to replace by code

Comment: `Not all guids would be possible to replace by code`, I was assuming anything that references a list could have the list it references changed by code.  If that's not the case then I guess it can't be done.